# EF -> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException -> Primary Key Guid.Empty Constraint -> Default Binding = newsequentialid()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, c#-5.0

I have a piece of code that is getting hit hard regularly throughout the day (very often).

It uses EntityFramework with Guids as Ids on the tables it is updating.  (Id = PK = Guid)

When a new record is inserted into the table it uses the table default binding of newsequentialid().  I would include the code that is running but it is very common EF C# code of. :

```
_context.SaveChanges();
```

What I am running into is it seems to be stomping on itself when this code is hit and inserting a new record.  The error that is returned is. :

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
```

I ran a sql profilier on it and it is actually erroring saying that it cannot perform an insert due to primary key constraint of 000-0000.... aka Guid.Empty().

So, my current thought is that it running so often that all the requests for newsequentialid() are stomping on each other causing this issue.

I am hoping someone else has had this or similar issue and can comment on this.  I think I ran into this issue quite some time ago and read that the solution was to switch out the EF to ADO.NET.

Comment: Personally, when using GUIDs, I prefer to call `Guid.NewGuid()` in code and pass it to the database myself; this way I can use it again for children in the object graph w/o having to get the derived value back from the db. The only time I worry about having the db generate my IDs is using `int` or something that needs to be sequential. I know this doesn't necessarily answer your question, but I thought I'd suggest a different approach.

Comment: @Joe I think your comment is the answer - there is no need to have the db generate a globally unique id or incur the overhead of doing so.

Comment: Unfortunately, in this system, this is our system wide standard.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this issue and solved it by changing the property "StoreGeneratedPattern" to "identiy" in the EF designer.

I would like to post a picture but it seems that i don't have enough reputation points.